# Caller's options infect Bash function

Tags: bash

A Bash function `function foo { ... }` inherits its caller's shell options like (for instance) `-f` or `extglob`. What if

1. I do not wish `foo` to inherit its caller's shell options,
2. spawning a subshell like `function foo { (...); }` would be too slow and waste too much electric power, and
3. the caller expects `foo` to return data by setting the caller's shell variables, as, for example, `function foo { ... CALLERS_VAR1=datum1; CALLERS_VAR2=datum2; ... }`.

How, please?

I am not free to re-engineer the caller. I am only free to write `foo`.

(If you wish to know my application, I am coding a *bash-completion* function, which I have never done before. However, as far as I know, you can address my question without familiarity with *bash-completion.*)

Comment: `would be too slow and waste too much electric power` ? Computers are there to use - it's not like a single one process is going to save you. I think the duplicate is good enough to give you `foo() { reset="$(set +o)$(shopt -p)"; : do sutf; eval "$reset"`. Prefer `foo()` over `function foo`, see [bash deprecated syntax](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete), As for bash completion [it sets extglob always](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/blob/master/bash_completion#L45).

Comment: KamilCuk I must disagree with your remark regarding speed and power. You're not talking about an extra 10 microseconds, but more like a millisecond. Computers are indeed there to use, as you say, but computers' *power-conserving facilities* are likewise there to use. Batteries appreciate the effort! Regarding `set +o`, though, I did not know that technique. That makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: `10 microseconds, but more like a millisecond` In case of shell, almost every command is an external process. Every `$(..)` and every part of pipeline, every `<<<` and every `<(..)` is a separate process. There are thousand processes executed in each script on your system. One more is really not going to make a difference. Overall, it's a difference of perspective - for me, time I spent writing my scripts is the most valuable, thus code readability and maintainability is more valuable then speed.

Comment: Anyway, I'll fire up `perf` or similar - I'm curious does it take a millisecond? ;)

Comment: @KamilCuk I see. Thousand processes. Good point. (Regarding the millisecond, I didn't use `perf`, though that is a good idea; but I timed a shell loop that spawned a thousand subprocesses. The loop took about one second longer than a loop without subprocesses.)